# Value is updated on service but not on controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to detect when mobile media queries are activated on my page. To do so, I'm using a "phantom" div.

```
<div class="mobile-alert" mobile-mode></div>
```

The class `.mobile-alert` is set `display:none` when mobile media queries are activated and `display: block` when they aren't. Now I use the following directive:

```
.directive('mobileMode', ["shareProperties", function(shareProperties){
    return{
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            var mobileSize;
            $(window).resize(function(){
                var mobileSize = $(elem).is(':visible');
                shareProperties.setMobileSize(mobileSize);
            });

        }
    }
}])
```

It watches if this div is visible, and with that I know if page is on mobile mode or not. Then, on shareProperties service:

```
.factory("shareProperties", function(){
    var properties = {mobileSize: false};

    return {
        getMobileSize: function(){
            return properties.mobileSize;
        },
        setMobileSize: function(value){

            properties.mobileSize = value;
            console.log(this.getMobileSize());
        }

    };
})
```

I share this variable with some controllers. However, the variables are set inside this service, but when I try to use them on a controller, like `ctrl.mobileMode = shareProperties.getMobileSize;`, calling this function on HTML with `{{ctrl.mobileMode()}}` always displays false. Any ideas ?

Comment: That's because it's a primitive (numbers, strings, booleans, etc...) and isn't passed by reference.

Comment: ctrl.mobileMode is a primitive ? I didn't invoke the function getMobileSize.

Comment: `ctrl.mobileMode = shareProperties.getMobileSize`

This won't work, when you update `shareProperties.getMobileSize`, `ctrl.mobileMode` won't change because it's a primitive

Comment: You initially did `ctrl.mobileMode = shareProperties.getMobileSize` now `ctrl.mobileMode` is set to `false` not the reference `shareProperties.getMobileSize`. So even if you update it, it won't update your `ctrl.mobileMode`

Comment: I'm using the same logic with `ctrl.contentPadding = shareProperties.getNavStatus`, and calling it on `<div ng-class="ctrl.contentPadding()">` .In this case, the value of `ctrl.contentPadding` changes. I don't understand why It works in one case and doesn't in this one.

Comment: Ah yes, ok I see the actually issue now, please look at my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.directive('mobileMode', ["shareProperties", function(shareProperties){
    return{
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            var mobileSize;
            $(window).resize(function(){
                var mobileSize = $(elem).is(':visible');
                shareProperties.setMobileSize(mobileSize);
                scope.$apply();
            });

        }
    }
}])
```

You've done something outside of angular by listening on the `$(window).resize` event, because of this you have to tell angular `hey angular! update yourself`. You can achieve this by running the `scope.$apply()` above.